# 'vagrant up' gives 'An error occurred while downloading'

Tags: vagrant, vagrant-windows

I use Vagrant on my Linux and OS X machines without problem.
Now on Windows 10 (the preview with Bash for Windows) it fails while downloading my box, without specifying a proper error message:

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Box 'trusty' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    default: Box Provider: virtualbox
    default: Box Version: >= 0
==> default: Box file was not detected as metadata. Adding it directly...
==> default: Adding box 'trusty' (v0) for provider: virtualbox
    default: Downloading: http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/vagrant/trusty/current/trusty-server-cloudimg-amd64-vagrant-disk1.box
    default:
An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error
message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try
again.
```

I also tried downloading the box (so the URL is correct!) and adding it manually but this results in the same:

```
C:\> vagrant box add ubuntu/trusty64 c:\Users\michi\boxes\trusty-server-cloudimg-amd64-vagrant-disk1.box
==> box: Box file was not detected as metadata. Adding it directly...
==> box: Adding box 'ubuntu/trusty64' (v0) for provider:
    box: Unpacking necessary files from: file://c:/Users/michi/boxes/trusty-server-cloudimg-amd64-vagrant-disk1.box
    box:
An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error
message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try
again.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer in this github issue: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/6725#issuecomment-223733553

I installed the [VC++ 2010 redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8328) and `vagrant up` worked immediately!

Comment: Here is the Link to the current VC++ redistributable:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads-2647da03-1eea-4433-9aff-95f26a218cc0